# Understanding the definition of multiplicity for a nonsingular point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I’m reading the definition from Shafarevich:

If $P=(0,0)$ and the leading terms in the equation of the curve have degree $r$ then $r$ is called the multiplicity of $P$. Thus a nonsingular point has multiplicity 1.

I don’t understand how this definition applies, for example, to a parabola defined by $y=x^2$. Suppose I want to verify that $(0,0)$ is a nonsingular point by computing its multiplicity: the leading term here is $x^2$, so multiplicity should be 2, which cannot be, because $(0,0)$ is indeed nonsingular. Also, how would the definition change if $P \neq (0,0)$?

Comment: You must be misquoting Shafarevich. What is the precise statement.  What does 'equation of the curve mean'.

Comment: There’s a curve described by $f(x,y)=0$, which is the equation he’s talking about

Comment: http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Shafarevich.pdf   It is at page 14

Comment: OK, so the polynomial in this case would $y-x^2=f(x,y)$ which does have linear terms.

Comment: Yes, but the leading term is not linear

Comment: What does 'the leading term' mean? He says on teh bottom of Pg. 13 that $f$ is non-singular at $(0,0)$ if it has a non-zero constant or linear term. This means that we can write $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x^iy^j$$ and $a_{i,j}\ne0$ for some $i+j\leqslant 1$. In other words, $f$ is singular at the origin if and only if it only has higher powers of $x$ and $y$. Clearly $f(x,y)=y-x^2$ is then non-singular since $a_{0,1}=1$.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to understand his definition of multiplicity of a nonsingular point. I guess his definition of “leading term” is not even clear to me at this point: I though he meant the highest power terms, like in a polynomial

Comment: Using my notation above, what he means that is that $f$ has multiplicity $r$ at $(0,0)$ if $\min \{k:\exists a_{i,j}\ne 0,\, i+j=k\}$. So, for example, the multiplicity of $y-x^2$ at $(0,0)$ is clearly $1$ since if $i+j=0$ then $a_{i,j}=0$ but $a_{0,1}=1\ne 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112519/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-cip).

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think your comment on the minimum over all $k$ is missing some terms. Could you recall what was discussed in chat?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question as you, and I came to this question in search of help, so I will post an answer for anyone else who stumbles upon it.

When Shafarevich says the word "leading term", he means the term with **minimal** total degree. In the example above, $f(x,y) = y-x^2$ has a term with degree one, so the multiplicity of $(0,0)$ is $1$.

Suppose $(0,0)$ is a singular point of $g(x,y) = a + bx + cy + h(x,y)$, where $h$ has terms of degree $\ge 2$. By taking partial derivatives, one can see that $a=b=c=0$, so the claim that every singular point has multiplicity $\ge 2$ holds.